# How to retrieve the file creation date from ftp

Tags: java, ftp, cmd

I am using the library `com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FileTransferClient` to download the files from ftp server.

I am trying to retrieve the ftp file creation date using the method `FileTransferClient getModifiedTime(java.lang.String remoteFileName)`

But receiving the below error:

> com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 550 command MDTM is not
>   available for 'AAAA.BBBB.CCCC.DDDDDD.EEEEEEEEEE(0)'

I tried using the command `quote mdtm 'filename'` from command line and same response.

Looked at both the links

1. http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm
2. http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm

But could not find any alternative or workaround for this..Any thoughts?

EDIT: Tried the command `remotehelp` and below is the response :

> 214-The server-FTP commands are: 214-ABOR,*ACCT,*ALLO, APPE, CDUP, 
>   CWD, DELE, FEAT, HELP, LANG, LIST, MDTM, MKD 214-MODE, NLST, NOOP,
>   OPTS, PASS, PASV, PORT,  PWD, QUIT, REIN, REST, RETR, RMD 214-RNFR,
>   RNTO, SITE, SIZE, *SMNT, SYST, STAT, STOR, STOU, STRU, TYPE, USER
>   214-ADAT, AUTH, CCC, PBSZ, PROT, EPSV, EPRT 214-The commands preceded
>   by '*' are not implemented

As per the response server should support the command `MDTM`..Am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As the response code said, the server you connected to does not support asking last-modified time of file.

MDTM (get last-modified time) is an extension, so it's optional for FTP server to implement it. Furthermore, there is no command for asking file creation time in any FTP-related RFC propose.

It's unlikely possible to do what you want by using FTP unless your FTP server has command for asking file creation time.

Comment: Hi, When i did remotehelp command on server it is showing mdtm as the valid command..any thoughts..edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think one could use

```
getRaw();
```

Javadoc tells:

> getRaw()
>
> public java.lang.String getRaw()
>
> Returns:
>
> Returns the raw server string.

So if you query the server with "LIST", you should get a List off all files including last modification time.
The you have to parse out the modification time manually.